# Url doesn't navigate in self window

Tags: actionscript-3

```
clickMeh.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var url:String = "http://www.mysite.com/";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    navigateToURL(request,'_self');
}
```

i have this code but each time i click the button i'm getting new tab opened like it was "_blank" directive.

Comment: try '_top' or '_parent',

also the reference says: `You cannot navigate the special windows "_self", "_top", or "_parent" if your SWF file is contained by an HTML page that has set the allowScriptAccess to "none", or to "sameDomain" when the domains of the HTML file and the SWF file do not match.`

Comment: changed to _parent and allowScriptAccess to "always".... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicating my comment to make the question answered:

try `_top` or `_parent`, also the [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) says:

> You cannot navigate the special windows "_self", "_top", or "_parent" if your SWF file is contained by an HTML page that has set the allowScriptAccess to "none", or to "sameDomain" when the domains of the HTML file and the SWF file do not match.

Comment: yay, copying my comment "changed to _parent and allowScriptAccess to "always".... thanks"