# Is it possible to navigateURL without popping up a browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a project that runs swf files. What i'm trying to do is to navigate to a url in that exact window without popping up a browser.

I've tried this :

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"),"_self");
```

but this always pops up a browser windows.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817674/url-doesnt-navigate-in-self-window

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this behaiviour is customizable. You can try to use ExternalInterface to call JavaScript funtion that will do what you need.